# Save only first fragment on Android back stack

Tags: android, android-fragments

From some time I have problems with fragments and the back stack. In my app I one activity - `MainActiviy`with drawer and some fragments.

My `MainActivity` looks something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final int HOME_NUM = 0;
private static final int ABOUT_NUM = 1;

    private boolean firstFragmentChange = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        //Some other initalizations

        displayFragment(HOME_NUM);
    }

    private void displayFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case HOME_NUM:
            fragment = new MainFragment();
            break;
        case ABOUT_NUM:
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        if (!firstFragmentChange) {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        firstFragmentChange = true;
    }
}
```

The `MainFragment` class looks like this:

```
public class MainListFragment extends ListFragment implements
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int ADD = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_main, container,
                false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_fragment_ab, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_add:
            displayFragment(ADD);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void displayFragment(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case ADD:
            fragment = new AddFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

What I want and what I am trying to achieve is to have on my back stack the first (initial) fragment, that is `MainFragment`. However, even after adding `addToBackStack()` in `MainActivity` it still doesn't work. Now I have on my back stack doubled `Add` fragment when I get to this fragment.

Maybe to describe it better it looks like this:

Now:

```
Start -> MainActivity (displays) MainFragment ->(press button)-> AddFragment
(back pressed)-> AddFragment (still stays) -> exit app
```

How I want it to work:

```
Start -> MainActivity (displays) MainFragment ->(press button)-> AddFragment
(back pressed)-> MainFragment -> exit app
```

Can someone tell me how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You always get a new Fragment instance by pressing your buttons. Better tag them and check if they are already around. This way you will always have one instance of your specific Fragment and your problem will be gone.

Also if you wanna check if a Fragment is already added to the backstack use `Fragment.getBackStackEntryCount()`. If it returns 0 there is no Fragment in the backstack.

Something like this, maybe you have to modify it a bit, but you should get the idea:

```
private void displayFragment(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction();

    switch (position) {
    case HOME_NUM:
        fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FIRST_TAG);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new MainFragment();
        }
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, FIRST_TAG); // Set the tag
        break;
    case ABOUT_NUM:
        fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(SECOND_TAG); 
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new AboutFragment();
        }
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, SECOND_TAG); // Set the tag
        break;    
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount == 0) {
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Also make sure to have this method once! There is no need for a additional method in your Fragment.

Comment: I'll check it, thank you. But what do you mean that I need to have this method only once? So in my MainFragment how will Android know what to do with actions made on buttons?

Comment: You can always refer from a Fragment to the Activity and call methods there. The idea is to have one method which is in charge for all fragment transactions.

Comment: to be honest, it isn't the best option I think to call method from Activity. Mostly because you need to make this method `public static` which cannot be used there because of other methods/variables in `displayFragment()`. What's more I think that this is not correct with coding rules.

Comment: Try this in your Fragment: `((MainActivity)getActivity()).displayFragment(...);`. Also you could use a Callback to invoke this method.

Comment: Still the last fragment is duplicated.